# can't set selected value in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have the following html select code where I can see the country list but
can't see the selected country (the first item in the list selected instead):

```
<select class="selectpicker" [(ngModel)]="trip.country" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCountry($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c.country">{{c.country.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

The component ts file:

```
export class Trip1Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() public trip: Trip;
  public countries: Country[] = [];
  private selectedCountry: Country;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: WebStorageService) {
    this.countries = this.storage.get("countries");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onSelectCountry(this.trip.country);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); 
    }, 10);

  }

onSelectCountry(val)  {
    this.selectedCountry = val;
  }
...
}
```

The country list from console:

[image: countries list from console]

The country object in trip:

[image: the country object in trip]

Can you advise what should be changed in the code in order to see the selected
value correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ngValue should be just **`c`**

```
 <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.country.name}}</option>
```

Comment: I've tried with both [ngValue]="c" and [ngValue]="c.country" and getting the exact same result.

Comment: check this sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15cgac?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: The example used an id for the country and that's solve the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this one**

```html
<select class="selectpicker" [(ngModel)]="trip.country" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCountry($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" (click)="selectCountry(c)">{{c.country.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

**In TS**

```js
selectCountry(val)  {
    this.selectedCountry = val;
  }
```